# TypeError: name() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not str python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to use [Gender Computer](https://github.com/tue-mdse/genderComputer) for generate gender data to my dataframe. This is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

crd = os.getcwd()
df_hash = pd.read_csv(crd +"\\hashtag4.csv", encoding="utf-8")

from genderComputer import GenderComputer
gc = GenderComputer()

df_hash['gender'] = gc.resolveGender(df_hash['full_name'], None)
```

But I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Desktop\recsys\genderComputer-master\nameUtils.py in is_cyrillic(uchr)
    109 def is_cyrillic(uchr):
--> 110     try: return cyrillic_letters[uchr]
    111     except KeyError:

KeyError: 'CoffeeCaine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-6fd7ed6bd781> in <module>
----> 1 df_hash['gender'] = gc.resolveGender(df_hash['full_name'], None)

~\Desktop\recsys\genderComputer-master\genderComputer.py in resolveGender(self, name, country)
    558         def resolveGender(self, name, country):
    559                 '''Check if name is written in Cyrillic or Greek script, and transliterate'''
--> 560                 if only_cyrillic_chars(name) or only_greek_chars(name):
    561                         name = unidecode(name)
    562 

~\Desktop\recsys\genderComputer-master\nameUtils.py in only_cyrillic_chars(unistr)
    115 def only_cyrillic_chars(unistr):
    116     return all(is_cyrillic(uchr)
--> 117         for uchr in unistr if uchr.isalpha())
    118 
    119 '''Check whether a given character is written in Greek'''

~\Desktop\recsys\genderComputer-master\nameUtils.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    115 def only_cyrillic_chars(unistr):
    116     return all(is_cyrillic(uchr)
--> 117         for uchr in unistr if uchr.isalpha())
    118 
    119 '''Check whether a given character is written in Greek'''

~\Desktop\recsys\genderComputer-master\nameUtils.py in is_cyrillic(uchr)
    110     try: return cyrillic_letters[uchr]
    111     except KeyError:
--> 112         return cyrillic_letters.setdefault(uchr, 'CYRILLIC' in unicodedata.name(uchr))
    113 
    114 '''Check whether a given string is written in Cyrillic'''

TypeError: name() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not str
```

This is what inside `df_hash['full_name']:

[image]

What I know is I need to encode all values in the column. And you can see the error shows up from `CoffeeCaine` which is from index 3. I already tried to encode the column or entire dataframe like `df_hash['full_name'].str.encode("utf-8")`, `df_hash.full_name.str.encode('utf-8')`, load the csv with encoding, or load into dataframe then save it to csv again with encoding, but still no effect.

I tried just using a string like 'John' instead of the column, it works, it will create new column and all values is 'male'. Also when I drop `CoffeeCaine` rows, the error shows up again on certain values like before. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting that the issue is that you are passing a whole DataFrame rather than a single str. So it iterates over the entries of the DataFrame rather than the characters of the str. Try the following:

```py
df_hash['gender'] = df_hash['full_name'].apply(lambda s: gc.resolveGender(s, None))
```